# Why notification:table create table with primary key is uuid

Tags: laravel, uuid

I created a migration by artisan command `php artisan notifications:table` and it created a migration file with schema

```
        Schema::create('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->integer('type');
            $table->morphs('notifiable');
            $table->text('data');
            $table->timestamp('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

So, in this case, is using `uuid` as primary key recommended? and why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter , at the end you will catch the data by the owner (notifiable)